# css not loading consistently

Tags: html, css

I'm building the landing page for our app, and i found some inconsistencies when opening up my page on google chrome. I designed the page to have the text be on the right side of the picture.  However sometimes when i refresh the page, the text drops below the picture.  This doesn't happen all the time, but if i keep pressing refresh, the text will eventually drop.

I'm assuming that it's because i might be putting my width of the div a little too narrow. but i dont understand why it works sometimes and not other times.

the site is on : https://www.thedashapp.com/about.html

(disclaimer: the site isn't supposed to be live yet, so the links aren't all properly hooked up yet, and the app still hasn't launched)

See pictures:

How it's supposed to look like:[image]
[image]

What happens when i click refresh a couple times:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Happens to me in chrome every time I load it.Who are you floating .bio left?

Comment: @j08691 are u asking why im floating bio left?  it's cause if i dont, the bottom half of the text will crawl under the pictures

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off putting the text in a separate div, and perhaps the image too. Then apply `float:left;` to both the div containing the text and the image or div that contains the image. I'm pretty sure that'll fix it.